# Tableau - Server Access Right

Tags: tableau-api

I have created a Tableau site for trial basis.
I do have all privilege for my site.

How do I get server administrator right on Tableau Online?

Comment: What you have tried ?

Answer (score 1):

You can get a brief idea of server and site administrator from below link

https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/sites.htm

> The server administrator sets up Tableau Server—they install and upgrade it, configure the services that run on Tableau Server, back it up, and perform other tasks that pertain to running Tableau Server as a whole. Server administrators also create sites as needed. (Site administrators don't have permissions to create sites.)

On local tableau server I am aware of server administrator. For Online tableau I am not aware of server administrator.